# Why is Javascript equating 5 == 8 as true?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, equality

So I have 2 check-boxes:

```js
var statusList = [];
function updateStatusString(x) {
    if (statusList != null) {
        if (statusList.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < statusList.length; i++) {
                if (parseInt(statusList[i]) == parseInt(x)) {
                    statusList[i] = 123;
                } else {
                    statusList.push(x);
                }
            }
        } else {
            statusList.push(x);
        }
    }
    alert(statusList);
}
```

```html
<label>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="Active" value="5" onchange=updateStatusString("5")>&nbsp;"Active"</label>
<label>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="NonActive" value="8" onchange=updateStatusString("8")>&nbsp;"Active"</label>
```

When I click a checkbox it adds it to a JavaScript list, if it's already in the list I want to overwrite it with another value (123 in this example).

But when I click the second one (doesn't matter the order, the 2nd element is always 123 for some reason.

Where as I would expect if I click the top check-box it would be a list containing '5', then clicking the second check-box I would expect 5,8 but it alerts as `5,123`, don't really see why it's doing this as `5==8` is false... any ideas?

**Updated algorithm to fix underlying issue:**

In-case anyone ever finds this useful I changed the algorithm to a better alternative:

```
var statusList = [];
function updateStatusString(x) {
    if (statusList.length > 0) {
        if (statusList.includes(x)) {
            var idx = statusList.indexOf(x);
            if (idx != -1) {
                statusList.splice(idx, 1);
            }
        }
        else {
            statusList.push(x);
        }
    } else {
        statusList.push(x);
    }
    alert(statusList);
}
```

Comment: your algorithm also contains a mistake(probably).
it will add x to the list for every non-x in the array, which it will turn into 123's once it reaches the end of the forloop.

(the array [1,2,3,4,5] checking x=6 will first turn into [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,6] (i = 5) and then into [1,2,3,4,5,123,123,123,123,123] (i = 10))

Comment: I agree with @recurringError . Every index of the Loop you either push or replace so the more in the list the more will be added. Also want to add that even with 2 buttons the list will grow with number of clicks (even if you cash value or so) since if you click 8 the 3:rd time it will not find it only 123 so will add another 8.

Comment: @JohanSellberg yeah just went with another approach after seeing the logic fallacies the answers highlighted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first iteration:

since status list is empty you are adding 5 in it,

second iteration:

statulsList = [5]

you are adding 8 so now the statusList value is [5,8] which means also the length is 2,

so we have a third iteration which in this case 8 === 8 .

if you want to have it different save the length of the status list before adding the other item on the list.

```js
var statusList = [];
function updateStatusString(x) {
    if (statusList != null) {
        if (statusList.length > 0) {
           var lengthStat = statusList.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < lengthStat; i++) {
                if (parseInt(statusList[i]) == parseInt(x)) {
                    statusList[i] = 123;
                } else {
                    if(! (statusList.indexOf(x) != -1))
                        statusList.push(x);
                }
            }
        } else {
            statusList.push(x);
        }
    }
    alert(statusList);
}
```

```html
<label>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="Active" value="5" onchange=updateStatusString("5")>&nbsp;"Active"</label>
<label>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="NonActive" value="8" onchange=updateStatusString("8")>&nbsp;"Active"</label>
```

Answer (score 6):

Because you are iterating over the `statusList`. At first iteration you check if 5 == 8, then moves to else part and inserts `8` in `statusList`. Your statusList is = [5, 8]. For next iteration, this becomes true `statuslist[i]` will be 8 and 8===8 and your statement - `statusList[i] = 123;` will replace last inserted `8`value with `123`. Therefore, your statusList array will have `["5", 123]`.

```js
var statusList = [];

function updateStatusString(x) {
  const input = parseInt(x);
  if (statusList != null) {
    if (statusList.includes(input)) {
      const idx = statusList.indexOf(input);
      statusList[idx] = 123;
    } else {
      statusList.push(input);
    }
    alert(statusList);
  }
}
```

```html
<label>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="Active" value="5" onchange=updateStatusString("5")>&nbsp;"Active"</label>

<label>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="NonActive" value="8" onchange=updateStatusString("8")>&nbsp;"Active"</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the loop was causing your issue.

1. You were checking for the existence of `x`, which on the first loop was false
2. You pushed it to the array
3. Second loop, it existed and was replaced with 123

You can dramatically simplify your code by removing one of the if checks, and using [array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of looping and checking equality.

**Edit:** Added a third input to demonstrate *123* being added.

```js
var statusList = [];
function updateStatusString(x) {
    if (statusList != null) {
      if (statusList.includes(x)) {
          statusList[statusList.indexOf(x)] = 123;
      } else {
          statusList.push(x);
      }
    }
    
    alert(statusList);
}
```

```html
<label>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="Active" value="5" onchange=updateStatusString("5")>&nbsp;"Active"</label>
<label>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="NonActive" value="8" onchange=updateStatusString("8")>&nbsp;"Active"</label>
<label>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="NonActive" value="8" onchange=updateStatusString("5")>&nbsp;"Active"</label>
```

Comment: But if you push on include instead of replacing value you will end up with [5,8,123] after [5,8] instead of the intended [5,8] and later [5,123] (or whatever button you pressed again)

Comment: Says "if it's already in the list I want to overwrite it with another value". So first click on 5 it is 5 in the list. next click this time on 8 he will have 5,8 and if you click 8 again he wants to override the 8.. so 5, 123... A 3rd click on 8 would ofc then give 5, 123, 8

Comment: @Lewis - Don't push `123`. Find the index of element and then assign `123` at that index.

Comment: @JohanSellberg , randomSoul - Thanks for the heads up. I've updated the answer to reflect your comments.